# How can I create a generic function only for a certain class hierarchy?

Tags: c#, generics

Can I define a generic method that accepts only an argument only from a certain class hierarchy, the parent and child classes?

```
void DoSomething<T>(T input) {}

class A {}
class B : A {}
```

Here I want to use something like:

```
void DoSomething<A>(A input) {}
```

and I want this to work also for all cases within the class hierarchy:

```
A objA;
B objB;

DoSomething(objA);
DoSomething(objB);
```

Comment: Use a [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Comment: But note that you could simply declare it as `void DoSomething(A input)`. Are you sure making it generic has any advantages for your use case?

Comment: Is just a design issue, I have whole class hierarchy with different attributes, I encounter need to oerload method for every child class, that is why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by applying a generic [constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) for base class

```cs
void DoSomething<T>(T input) where T : A
{
}
```

Comment: Is this ok? //// public bool SendReceive<T1, T2>(T1 request, ref T2 response) where T1 : A where T2:B ////

Comment: @user3597222 Syntax is ok, but logically it isn't a best solution, imho

Comment: @user3597222 Depends on what you mean by "OK"? Yes it will work, but I wouldn't do it that way.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the classes you use as constraints must be at least as visible as the generic class itself, e.g., `internal` (aka "default") classes cannot be used as constraints of a `public` generic class.